# Ubuntu Server 18 Internet working, but can't pull/install updates from Internet

Tags: command-line, 18.04, scripts

my ubuntu server 18 can ping google successfully but I can't install updates and even required software. This is what I got
[result of sudo apt-get update command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vT06C.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Could you please post the result of the command, coping and pasting from your terminal? Format it to code using the tool `{}` or select the text and press Ctrl+K

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, once installed, wants you to use different software sources other than the general default.  See [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) which describes how and why to change,  then go to [this list of repositories](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) and pick one close to you with a fast Internet connection which dshows in the rightmost column it is current (in green).

Since I am in Oregon, I would normally pick the [Oregon State University Open Source Lab](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ubuntu.osuosl.org-archive) or [Portland State University](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirrors.cat.pdx.edu). The idea is to pick a current, up to date source, close to you to minimize Internet traffic; but *current, up to date* is more important than *local*, so because both of those are not current, I pick the [Pacific Northwest National Lab](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.pnl.gov-archive) up near Hanford, instead.

If you pick one halfway across the planet like this one in [Suid Afrika](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/mirror.lnx-solutions.com-archive), that's OK, too; it's your choice.